# Subfolder call folder Golang

Tags: go, import, subdirectory

my project name is family. I want to use struct which defined in father.go, use it in son.go. What I have to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`go.mod`:

```
module family
```

`father\father.go`:

```
package father
type Dad struct { Age int }
```

`father\son\son.go`:

```
package main

import (
   "family/father"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   d := father.Dad{40}
   fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Comment: Hi, if before inside father.go must import to use data of son.go, how can i do it? @Steven Penny

Comment: @manhkhoa168, you can't because that would be an import cycle. There are plenty of questions about that on SO, but in short: don't create tiny packages. Make father.go and son.go part of the same package.

Answer (score 0):

1. father/father.go

```
package father
type Father struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Job string `json:"job"`
}
```

2.father/son/son.go

```
package son

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/yaocanwei/demo/father"
)

type Son struct {
    father.Father
    Hobby string `json:"hobby"`
}

func (son *Son) EchoJob() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", son.Father.Job)
}
```

3.main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/yaocanwei/demo/father/son"
)

func main()  {
    s := &son.Son{}
    s.Job = "senior engineer"
    fmt.Println(s.EchoJob())
}
```